# Is it possible to put a result of SUM() ORDER BY in original table?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Is it possible to add (put) a result of SUM() ORDER BY in original table?

```
A　Table
Columns   id,value,val2
1,200,1
2,300,3
3,300,2
4,400,4
5,100,1
6,100,1
7,100,1
8,100,4

TOTAL 1 = 500 * 1.5 = 750
 

B　Table
Columns   id,value,val2
1,100,50
2,500,33
3,600,0
5.900,0


Ideal
B　Table
Columns   id,value,val2
1,100,770
2,500,33
3,600,0
5.900,0
```

SELECT A.id , SUM ( value)*1.5 AS VITAMIN_D  FROM A WHERE val2  in (SELECT id from B)

I would like to UPDATE val3 in B-table to add The results of SUM(value).
How Can I do?

Comment: Create a view instead, to avoid data inconsistency.

Comment: Show desired output. And - table B have 4 columns, but you show 3 values only.

Comment: A()B_table is as am exple . Actually , They have 60000000 records.
Is making the view an efficient way ?

Comment: Sorry I made the mistake.. I modified that.

Comment: Nevertheless show desired output for this example data.

Comment: jarlh  I would like to know how to use the view.

Comment: Is it possible to execute it by  single query if it is

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a correlated subquery:

```
update tableb
set val3 = (
    select sum(value) * 1.5
    from tablea a
    where a.val2 = tableb.id
)
```

Comment: Thank you for answwering it.  ORA-01427: Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: @puss . . . The subquery is an aggregation subquery with no `group by`.  It cannot return more than one row.  Perhaps you have triggers on the table or something else is going on, but this appears to answer your question.